# Ruby on Rails3 ':' vs '=>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, aptana

In Ruby On Rails 3, is right to use

```
validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
```

instead

```
validates :name,  presence: true, :length => { maximum: 50 }
```

?

In the first case, even the code works, Aptana3 still saying that are errors, i have to change to second method to it quit says that errors are present.

Why?

Rails 3.2.10
ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]

Comment: New syntax is only for when using a hash with a symbol, perhaps part of the issue.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant All those keys are symbols.

Answer (score 1):

What your IDE thinks is correct may be different than what is actually correct.

IntelliJ, for example, requires setting the Ruby language level to get the new hash syntax.

Comment: This is correct. The new hash syntax apparently has a bug in Aptana (or at least did). See the following forum post: http://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/suggestions/303-ruby-syntax-highlightingerror-indication

Comment: @mbaumbach Interesting; too bad it's a year old and the link to the issue on that page is broken :( *sigh* Ah, internet.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Rails I think, and everything to do with your ruby version.

You probably need to configure Aptana to use ruby 1.9. But what's strange is that you're also using the new syntax in the second version (`presence: true`), so the problem might be somewhere else...

But the point is, the first version is what you should use.

Comment: I suspect the "error" would be a simple (inasmuch as parsing Ruby is simple) parsing issue with the value type.

Answer (score 0):

One thing: It has nothing to do with Aptana. But it shouldn't give that warning/ errors.
Yoy might have have more than one version of ruby installed. Make sure that Aptana is using ruby >= 1.9.

To list all ruby versions installed on your system:

```
ruby -v 

rvm list (if used rvm to install rubies)
```

Before ruby 1.9, hashes were declared like:

```
:key => "value"
```

From 1.9 onwards, to reduce typing load, this shorthand has been made available:

```
key: "value"
```

However, when working with rails, I have found a few irregularities like:

```
validates :some_attr, presence: true, :if => { block }  # this works
```

But this doesn't:

```
validates :some_attr, presence: true, if: { block }  # this DOES NOT works
```

Same is the case with lambda, Proc etc. Basically where ever we need to specify a block.